# can/should iCal property parametrs be escaped?

Tags: parsing, icalendar, vcalendar, rfc5545, vcal

specifically, the CN (common name) parameter, e.g.

> ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe,Eng:mailto:jd@some.com

The RFC is vague on this, IMHO. It is very clear about **property values** of **type** TEXT, but for this parameter it just says "*The parameter value is text*". Anyways, the escaping specified for TEXT type doesn't seem complete for parameter values (e.g. ':' is not escaped).

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Davka,

Yes, parameter values can be escaped by surrounding the value in double-quotes.  Parameter values must be escaped if they contain any of the following characters:

```
; - semicolon
: - colon
, - comma
```

It is illegal to have a double quote `"` character inside parameter values, so they should be deleted (or otherwise removed from the parameter value).

So, with your above example, the correct escaping is this:

```
ORGANIZER;CN="John Doe,Eng":mailto:jd@some.com
```

Note that once the first (unquoted) colon `:` is encountered, parsing engines treat the rest as the *property value*.  It is legal to use the colon `:` character inside property values, so the colon in `mailto:jd@some.com` doesn't need to be escaped.

We can break the line into it's parts:

- `ORGANIZER` - property name
- `;` - parameter delimiter
- `CN` - parameter name
- `=` - parameter value delimiter
- `"John Doe,Eng"` - parameter value
- `:` - property value delimiter
- `mailto:jd@some.com` - property value

Here's a quote from RFC 5545 Section 3.2 that explains when parameter values are surrounded with double-quotes, and tells us double-quotes are illegal in parameter values:

> Property parameter values that contain
>   the COLON, SEMICOLON, or COMMA
>   character separators MUST be specified
>   as quoted-string text values. Property
>   parameter values MUST NOT contain the
>   DQUOTE character.  The DQUOTE
>   character is used as a delimiter for
>   parameter values that contain
>   restricted characters or URI text. 
>   For example:
>
> DESCRIPTION;ALTREP="cid:part1.0001@example.org":The
>   Fall'98 Wild  Wizards Conference - -
>   Las Vegas\, NV\, USA

It's important to note that parameters can technically contain multiple values.  A comma is used to separate these multiple values:

(from Section 3.2.11 of RFC 5545:)

```
ATTENDEE;MEMBER="mailto:projectA@example.com","mailto:pr
 ojectB@example.com":mailto:janedoe@example.com
```

Not all iCalendar engines will accept multiple values on all parameters, but the following parameters SHOULD allow multiple values (according to the RFC):

- MEMBER
- DELEGATED-FROM
- DELEGATED-TO

Regards,

-Doug

Comment: I couldn't make the comma approach work in Outlook 2013 and just ended up specifying multiple ATTENDEE lines.

Comment: Yep, that's as intended.  The comma approach is to provide multiple aliases for the same person (i.e. a person with multiple e-mail addresses).

Comment: According to RFC6868, you can escape " to ^' so it is no longer illegal to have a double quote inside parameter values now.